# Possible to track location via android mobile gps using Google API?

Tags: php, google-api, tracking, geo

I have developed fleet management using `PHP`. Here i plan to track vehicle in real-time and store the locations in my database.

**My question is:** Possible to track location via android mobile gps using Google API?

If it is possible please give me a way to create this.

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: i make my question very simple

Answer (score 1):

PHP, which is a server-side language, can't query the device's location, instead the client application should get GPS location coordinates via Android's API and send it to the PHP server (for example via a POST request), then the server can handle the data and store it into the database.

Comment: Thanks for reply GrowingBrick you are right. My question is how to get GPS location please give me an example..!

Comment: Stackoverflow is full of examples for this, just search "android get GPS location", one of them could be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android